# Compile Error When Creating a Submit Button in VBA/Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a submit button in Excel 2016 using a macro with the below code

```
Sub Submitbutton14_Click()

Dim x As Outlook.Application
Dim y As Outlook.MailItem
Set x = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set y = oLapp.CreateItem(0)
With y
.Subject = ""
.CC = ""
.To = "test@email.com"
.Body = ""
.Attachments.Add '(path to the attachment,either hard coded or
                    ' variable)
.Display
End With
Set x = Nothing
Set y = Nothing
'
End Sub
```

When I run the macro I see a `Compile Error: Argument not Optional` with `Sub Submitbutton14_Click()` highlighted in yellow. Can you advise what I am doing wrong? I am completely new to VBA and have found this code online and have modified parts of it to fit my need?

Many Thanks

Comment: You need to add an attachment path

Comment: When adding the file path I see a `Run-time error 424: Object Required`. Using the debug option highlights `Set y = oLapp.CreateItem(0)` in yellow.

Comment: Use `x` instead of `oLapp`

Comment: Yes, the MSDN page uses olApp you use x. :)

Comment: OK thanks
I will give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an attachment path

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx

Source is required.

Also, you can use new outlook.application, rather than createobject.